# How to get Notepad ++ Highlight Feature in VS Code

Tags: syntax-highlighting, visual-studio-code

I want Notepad++ Highlight Feature in VS Code as shown in the image below.

Can you please help me on this?

[image: Notepad ++ Highlight Feature here]

Comment: It is unclear what you asking: highlight matching tag? attribute highlight? color theme?

Comment: very nice Alex...i want match-tag highlight along with attribute highlight include with yellow color

Comment: I've been using 'Text Marker (Highlighter)' by @Ryuichi Inagaki to have the 'Style Token' feature from Notepad++